# Google Apps Script Can't Find Folder [Shared Drives]

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to access a folder called 'Content Planning' in a Shared Drive, which is then supposed to find a subfolder called 'Content Docs'. The script runs successfully on my account, but when my colleague, who also has contributor access to the Shared Drive, runs the same script, the DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Content Planning").hasNext() method returns false.

We've confirmed that the script has the necessary permissions, and that my colleague can see and access the 'Content Planning' folder through the Google Drive interface. My colleague has also been made an editor of these folders. We're uncertain why the script is unable to find the folder when run by my colleague. Could there be a limitation or issue with the DriveApp API in this context?

Comment: Would you please add the script to the body your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.